# Xcode 8: UIView is not working as Subview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` and a seprate `UIView(MyTopView)` which I am showing on that `UIViewController`. In `Xcode 8`, after resolving that "Choose intital device" prompt the `UIView` is not aligning properly in that `UIViewController's` View.

This is my `UIViewController`.

Also, _viewTop is a container view which will hold MyTopView

[image]

And this is my `UIView` (MyTopView)
[image]

In `ViewController`, `viewWillAppear` method,

```
_myTopView = (MyTopView *)_viewTop;

NSLog(@"_myTopView: %@", _myTopView);
NSLog(@"self.view: %@", self.view);
```

But it takes incorrect frame for `UIView` (MyTopView)

```
_myTopView: <MyTopView: 0x7f9f5b5089f0; frame = (0 0; 625 832); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080002230c0>>
self.view: <UIView: 0x7f9f5b5084f0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000223080>>
```

Constraints warning

```
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000089560 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x7fc4c0408da0.height == MyTopView:0x7fc4c0604780.height - 832   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000088a20 V:|-(20)-[UIView:0x7fc4c0409c90]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc4c0408da0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000088ed0 V:[UIView:0x7fc4c0409c90]-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc4c0408da0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000087df0 MyTopView:0x7fc4c0604780.height == 150   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000088ed0 V:[UIView:0x7fc4c0409c90]-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc4c0408da0 )>
```

I was expecting that UIView will get displayed in that ViewController's View part.

It did used to work on ealrier version of Xcode7.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere during initialisation of `UIView(MyTopView)`, preferable in the designated `init`-method, set its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`-property to `false`/`NO`.

Ex.

```
- (instancetype) initWithCoder: (NSCoder*) aCoder
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithCoder: aCoder])) return nil;

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    return self;
}
```